# How to specify a repeated pattern within one string using `sub()` instead of `gsub()` in R

Tags: r, regex

I am aware of the many answer showing *how* to match multiple occurrences within a single string. However, I couldn't yet find an answer that would provide context as to **why** the following doesn't work:

```
## A string for which I want to replace `red` and `Red` with `RED`
x <- c("redflag flagred red and Red")

## This one works using `gsub()`
gsub("\\b(?:red|Red)\\b", "RED", x)
#[1] "redflag flagred RED and RED"
```

But is there a way to use `sub()` instead? The following doesn't work. It only matches the first occurrence and then stops:

```
sub("\\b(?:red|Red)\\b", "RED", x)
#[1] "redflag flagred RED and Red"
```

When checking the actual pattern it should match: https://regex101.com/r/X7DSB0/1 I am assuming this has something to do with the "global flag"?

I also tried adding a `+` or `{1,}` to get multiple matches but that doesn't work either:

```
## using a `+` doesn't work either
sub("\\b(?:red|Red)+\\b", "RED", x)
#[1] "redflag flagred RED and Red"

## using `{1,}` doesn't work either
sub("\\b(?:red|Red){1,}\\b", "RED", x)
#[1] "redflag flagred RED and Red"
```

What am I not understanding? How could I use `sub()` instead of `gsub()` for such an operation?

Comment: Just so you are aware your regex using the + would be wrong. That would also replace redredred, redRed, RedredRedredred, etc. e.g. `this redredRed is Redred` replaces to `this RED is RED` is you use `\\b(?:red|Red)+\\b`. I personally would forget about the group and OR statement and just use `\\b[rR]ed\\b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `g` in `gsub` stands for "global," which means that you are telling the regex engine to apply the substitution to the entire string.  On the other hand, `sub` just does the first replacement it encounters.

So the answer to your question is that you should use `gsub` if you intend to make every possible replacement:

```
gsub("\\b(?:red|Red)\\b", "RED", x)

[1] "redflag flagred RED and RED"
```

Comment: OK! `g` for global - of course! Does that also mean there is no way of altering the pattern in `sub()` (or `grepl()` etc.) for a given string to get multiple matches?

Comment: @Stefan Actually, I think there _is_ a way to make `sub` do multiple matches, but it involves using lookarounds, and feels more like a hack than anything else.  In production code, you would just use `gsub` here.

Comment: Alright that certainly makes sense. It's just me trying to better understand the regex pattern matching. I guess I could also try and go through the source code to see what's going on.

Comment: Yes, you can find out how `sub` is actually implemented.